# I don't know what's wrong with my code....Its not giving expected output

Tags: c-preprocessor

Here I used #pragma directive which is used to call a function before and after main function in a C program.
So, my expected output is--->   **Hi
                                HELLO
                                BYE**

But when executing this code I am getting output as--->   **HELLO**

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #pragma startup fun1
    #pragma exit fun2

    void fun1();
    void fun2();

    int main()
    {
        printf("\nHELLO");
        return 0;
    }

    void fun1()
    {
        printf("\nHi");
    }

    void fun2()
    {
        printf("\nBYE");
    }
```

Comment: Your question is missing a crucial bit of information: whether `#pragma startup` is even supported by your compiler.

Comment: I am using online compiler. I tried same code in 2-3 compilers but didn't get desired output.

Comment: Again: does the compiler you are using support `#pragma startup`? If I remember correctly, that's a feature of Borland TurboC. Are you using Borland TurboC?

Comment: No I am using gcc compiler. So, these directives are compiler dependent completely and only some compilers supports them.?

Answer (score 0):

From GCC's onlinedocs, [7 Pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html).

> The ‘#pragma’ directive is the method specified by the C standard for
>   providing additional information to the compiler, beyond what is
>   conveyed in the language itself. The forms of this directive (commonly
>   known as pragmas) specified by C standard are prefixed with STDC. A C
>   compiler is free to attach any meaning it likes to other pragmas. All
>   GNU-defined, supported pragmas have been given a GCC prefix.

That is to say, the `startup` and `exit` pragmas are not supported by GCC.

GCC does support using [attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes) to create similar behaviour. In particular:

```
__attribute__((constructor))
__attribute__((destructor))
__attribute__((constructor (PRIORITY)))
__attribute__((destructor (PRIORITY)))
```

For your example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun1() __attribute__((constructor));
void fun2() __attribute__((destructor));

int main (void){
  printf ("\nHELLO");
}

void fun1 (){
  printf ("\nHI");
}

void fun2 (){
  printf ("\nBYE\n");
}
```